# Create a variable based on specific condition from another column based on Year

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column that displays the first year in V2 where the value of V3 appears. However, after null values I would like to put again the first year for the reappearance of V3.

That is, in possession of the following data:

[image]

I would like to get a new V4 column as follows:

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Below are the data:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3), V2 = c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009), V3 = c(0, 0, 10, 25, 
35, 12, 15, 0, 15, 17, 13, 0, 0, 15, 12)), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` and `rleid` from `data.table` you can try the following. You can `group_by` both `V1` as well as a second group based on whether value in `V3` is zero. This assumes the years are in chronological order (if not, may need to add `arrange` by `V2` first).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(V1, grp = rleid(V3 != 0)) %>%
  mutate(V4 = ifelse(V3 == 0, 0, first(V2))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

**Output**

```
      V1    V2    V3    V4
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  2005     0     0
 2     1  2006     0     0
 3     1  2007    10  2007
 4     1  2008    25  2007
 5     1  2009    35  2007
 6     2  2005    12  2005
 7     2  2006    15  2005
 8     2  2007     0     0
 9     2  2008    15  2008
10     2  2009    17  2008
11     3  2005    13  2005
12     3  2006     0     0
13     3  2007     0     0
14     3  2008    15  2008
15     3  2009    12  2008
```